# Return a set of records only if they are in certain order

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with the following records ordered by timestamp

```
Id   TimeStamp      Action
--   ---------      ------
1    #1             ActionType#1
2    #2             ActionType#2
3    #3             ActionType#2
4    #4             ActionType#1
5    #5             ActionType#3
.    .              .
.    .              .
.    .              .
52   #52             ActionType#1
53   #53             ActionType#2
.    .              .
```

I want to write a query that would return to me a set of records, only if the records are in a particular sequence order.

For example on the data above, I want a query to:
"Get when Action#2 occurred after Action#1, in sequence, as per timestamp order."

Should return to me:

```
##First matching sequence

2    #2             ActionType#1 
3    #3             ActionType#2 
##Second matching sequence

52   #2             ActionType#1 
53   #3             ActionType#2
```

Note: This is in an ASP.NET application so LINQ style answers are welcome

Comment: Look at [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider an effective solution based on for loop over your table:

```
List<myRecordClass> myResults = new List<myRecordClass>();

for (int i = 1; i < myTable.Count; i++)
    {
        if (myTable.ElementAt(i).Action == myTable.ElementAt(i-1).Action)
        {
            myResults.Add(myTable.ElementAt(i - 1));
            myResults.Add(myTable.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }
```

This would allow you to implement other tests involving for example 3 consecutive records.

Comment: I think doing things at c# side is a good idea. It simplifies the problem. Just a note that the two actions are not necessarily equal. In my case I will have to modify this code a bit to first get the entries from DB in order, then compare each element in the sequence to the ordered sequence expected. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at Sql server side and reduce the size of resultset this way.

First find islands of constant `Action` when ordered by `TimeStamp` and them filter only islands of length= 2

```
select Id,TimeStamp, Action
from (
    select *, cnt = count(*) over(partition by grp)
    from (
        select *, grp = row_number() over(order by TimeStamp) - row_number() over(partition by Action order by TimeStamp) 
        from (values
                (1 ,'#1' ,'ActionType#1'),
                (2 ,'#2' ,'ActionType#2'),
                (3 ,'#3' ,'ActionType#2'),
                (4 ,'#4' ,'ActionType#1'),
                (5 ,'#5' ,'ActionType#3'),
                (51,'#51','ActionType#2'),
                (52,'#52','ActionType#2'),
                (53,'#53','ActionType#2')
        ) t (Id,TimeStamp,Action)  
     ) t1
   ) t2
where cnt=2
order by TimeStamp
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't check it (so I'll be happy to know if it works to you; I'm writing in mySQL):

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Id+1, a.Action 
   FROM #yourTable a
     INNER JOIN #yourTable (same one as above) b
       ON (a.Id=b.Id-1) AND (a.Action=b.Action);
```

Comment: sgivmal, Thanks but this will not work for two reasons. Timestamp is not necessarily with a difference of 1. The IDs also will not necessarily bewith a diff of 1. Moreover, the two actions are not necessarily equal. The sequence pattern could be : Action#1 then Action#3